# mapbox - loading different geojson choropleth overlays at different zoom levels

Tags: mapbox

so i have a mapbox base map and want to load a dynamic choropleth area map over the top of it. it will cover all continents. i've looked into doing this before using geojson but the resulting file was over 9mb. is there a way to have different geojson vectors loaded at different zoom levels as to reduce the file size ?

the reason the file was so big was because it was a very detailed vector overlay. basically i'd like to replicate the vectors of 'am map' but with the performance of mapbox, with much better vector resolution at bigger zoom levels. (http://www.amcharts.com/javascript-maps/)

the only other way to do this is by using geojson markers that are loaded on top of the base map, but this doesn't give the same visual impact of the fully coloured continent vectors..

any help would be greatly appreciated!

x

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could watch `zoomend` on the map to add/remove overlays as needed.

```
map.on('zoomend', function() {
    var currentZoom = map.getZoom();
    overlayGroup.clearLayers() //remove existing
    overlayGroup.addLayer(myZoomLevelMapping[currentZoom]) //add layer for this zoom level.
})
```

Comment: but this would be for pre-rendered bitmap layers right ? swapping layers in and out at different zoom levels. i'm not sure you can do that with a geojson object can u ? i thought it just loads it fully as the page is rendering ?

Comment: No, this is for vector objects. You can add and remove geojson layers as needed.